# Ordering MySQL string results without a defined Collation?

Tags: php, mysql, collation

Say I have the following results:

```
Mackay
Mackay Airport
Melbourne
Melbourne Airport
Sydney
Sydney Ac
Sydney Airport
```

How can I make it so they are ordered with Airport always at the top of them? Alphabetically, eg:

```
Mackay Airport
Mackay
Melbourne Airport
Melbourne
Sydney Airport
Sydney
Sydney Ac
```

A bit confused on how to make the Airports more prominent.

Comment: Do you consider only "Airport" or any alphanumeric word?

Comment: this is not 1NF - you should create an extra attribute `isAirport`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the following query covers all the cases, but it seems to work with your sample data:

```
select name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'Airport',1)
as l,
LOCATE('Airport',name) as r from 
(
select 'Sydney Airport' as name
union all
select 'Sydney'
union all
select 'Sydney Ac'
union all
select '
Mackay Airport'
union all
select 'Mackay'
union all
select 'Melbourne'
union all
select 'Melbourne Airport'
)a
order by l asc, r desc
```

with table it will look like

```
select name
from table1 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'Airport',1) ASC,
LOCATE('Airport',name) DESC
```

Comment: whoa, the query is much harder than sorting by hand :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't order by integer and string simultaneously, but you can derive the string to order by based on whether "Airport" is present.  It's silly, but it works:

```
ORDER BY IF(name NOT LIKE '% Airport', CONCAT(name, ' Birport'), name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the expected output ( even though the query is complicated).

```
SELECT t.name
FROM (
SELECT @num := IF(@num IS NULL, 1, @num+1) AS number, name
FROM places
ORDER BY IF ((name LIKE '% Airport'), SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE(' Airport', name) - 1), name)     DESC) t
ORDER BY t.number DESC;
```

Here is the example.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117b7/80